# How to sent push message from multiple apps in python

Tags: python, firebase

I have 2 different apps with `2 different credentials` for `firebase`. So `firebase_admin` is 2 times `initialised`.

import of firebase

```
from firebase_admin import credentials, messaging
```

Initialise 2 firebase_admins and assigne the json credentials.

```
#initialize firebase 1
json_file_first = location of the json one
credentials_first = credentials.Certificate(json_file_first)
first_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credentials_first,name="first")


#initialize firebase 2
json_file_second = location of the json second
credentials_second = credentials.Certificate(json_file_second)
second_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credentials_second, name="second")
```

Creating and sending the message:

```
def sendPushNotificationTest(title, msg, registration_token):
    message = messaging.MulticastMessage(    //here its using the default instance of firebase_admin
        notification=messaging.Notification(
        title=title,
        body=msg),
        tokens=registration_token

        )
      respons = messaging.send_multicast(message)
```

When creating/sending the push message it can be either with firebase_admin "first" or with firebase_admin "second". Where do i assign the right initialised firebase_admin.

Answer (score 0):

I did found the solution, its in the `response` below the message itself. You can add the `firebase_admin` instance.

```
def sendPushNotificationTest(title, msg, registration_token):
    message = messaging.MulticastMessage(   ///i think i have to define the sender before messaging
        notification=messaging.Notification(
        title=title,
        body=msg),
        tokens=registration_token

        )
 respons = messaging.send_multicast(message, app="first") //assign the right instance
```